# Strings seem to get lost when compiling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, compilation, signalr

I am creating a UWP app using Unity 3D. For some online capability I am utilizing SignalR. Since I keep getting strange errors once the app is compiled, I have implemented some basic logging functionality on the server side.

What I realized then is that part of the request URI is missing in the compiled product.

Here is what the server receives while I am debugging in Unity Editor:

```
Request: GET
URI: http://192.168.137.1:9000/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22ARHub%22%7D]
Remote Address: 192.168.137.1:53999
Headers: [Connection: keep-alive], [Host: 192.168.137.1:9000], [User-Agent: SignalR.Client.NetStandard/2.4.0.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0)]
```

And here's the supposedly same request once I've compiled to UWP. You'll see that one of the headers is missing as well as the name of the Hub to connect to.

```
Request: GET
URI: http://192.168.137.1:9000/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.0&connectionData=[%7B%7D]
Remote Address: 192.168.137.1:52933
Headers: [Host: 192.168.137.1:9000], [User-Agent: SignalR.Client.NetStandard/2.4.0.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0)]
```

And here is the exception that is logged on client side (UWP app):

```
Error: System.Security.SecurityException: The public key is not valid.
  at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.get_FullName () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.AppDomain.LoadSatellite (System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Version version, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly (System.Globalization.CultureInfo lookForCulture, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet (System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] localResourceSets, System.Boolean tryParents, System.Boolean createIfNotExists, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet (System.Globalization.CultureInfo requestedCulture, System.Boolean createIfNotExists, System.Boolean tryParents, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet (System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Boolean createIfNotExists, System.Boolean tryParents) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString (System.String name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.OnClosed () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Disconnect () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Display+DisplaysUpdatedDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+<>c__DisplayClass19_1.<ContinueWithNotComplete>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+<>c__70`1[T].<RunWithPreservedCulture>b__70_0 (System.Action`1[T] f, T state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Comparison`1[T].Invoke (T x, T y) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.RunWithPreservedCulture[T1,T2,TResult] (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+CulturePair preservedCulture, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.RunWithPreservedCulture[T] (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+CulturePair preservedCulture, System.Action`1[T] action, T arg) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+<>c__DisplayClass72_0.<ContinueWithPreservedCulture>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTaskSlot) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (System.Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean needsProtection) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completedTask, System.Boolean bCanInlineContinuationTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Object exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[TResult].TrySetFromTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Boolean lookForOce) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[TResult].ProcessCompletedOuterTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[TResult].InvokeCore (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[TResult].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish (System.Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Object exceptionObject) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult].TrySetException (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] exceptions) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.SetUnwrappedException[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, System.Exception e) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+TaskRunners`2+<>c__DisplayClass3_0[T,TResult].<RunTask>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+<>c__70`1[T].<RunWithPreservedCulture>b__70_0 (System.Action`1[T] f, T state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Comparison`1[T].Invoke (T x, T y) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.RunWithPreservedCulture[T1,T2,TResult] (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+CulturePair preservedCulture, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.RunWithPreservedCulture[T] (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+CulturePair preservedCulture, System.Action`1[T] action, T arg) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper+<>c__DisplayClass73_0`1[T].<ContinueWithPreservedCulture>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal (System.Threading.Tasks.Task& currentTaskSlot) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry (System.Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComCompatibleVersionAttribute..ctor (System.Int32 major, System.Int32 minor, System.Int32 build, System.Int32 revision) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Assets.Scripts.Controllers.SignalRControllerBehaviour.remove_ShowDevicesRequested (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (System.Object stateMachine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Display+DisplaysUpdatedDelegate.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation+<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch+SerializationDataAvailableDelegate.Invoke (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Can anyone tell me why this might happen and - more importantly - how I can fix it?

Also (I'm not sure if this is relevant), these are actually all zeroes, I didn't change anything. Shouldn't there be some proper addresses?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant code section on client-side:

```
[...]
_connection = new HubConnection(url);
_connection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
_connection.TraceWriter = connectionTraceWriter;

_proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("ARHub");

// subscribe to proxy and connection events

await _connection.Start();
[...]
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: I actually see rather one additional header `[Connection: keep-alive],` instead of one missing ... and also the hub info `[%7B%22Name%22:%22ARHub%22%7D]` which is present in your UWP log seems to rather be missing on the UnityEditor log than the other way round... And do you get any hint from `The public key is not valid.`?

Comment: @derHugo I'm sorry, I posted the two logs in the wrong order. It's fixed now. I've also posted the relevant code.

Comment: I am not sure about the public key thing. SignalR protocol requires a handshake where the server sends a response (including a key for identification) after the initial request. Since the requested Hub isn't correct, the key is probably wrong as well.

Comment: I guess you are refering to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codefest/2014/09/11/signalr-und-unity-in-euren-multiplayer-indie-games/) or something similar ... unfortunately with the provided code I don't see where the difference should come from

Comment: Yes it’s a similar use case. I‘m using the .Net Standard 2.0 DLL of SignalR though, which is now supported by Unity.